# See course overview withoug logging in in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have recently installed Moodle 3.9 in one of my subdomains (cursos.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com).

I would like this webpage to have the ability to navigate through the courses, see the instructor, when the course starts, see what you will learn, the requirements, course content.

It would be something similar to Udemy, where the potential students can see a list of courses, but after clicking on them, they discover the complete summary and specifications of the course (see this page as an example https://www.udemy.com/course/python-for-data-science-and-machine-learning-bootcamp/).

How it works now is that the potential students can see a list of courses in the landing page. However, when they click on the course, it goes to the logging section.

I would like the students to see the page of the course, and later, to enrol in the course if they decide so.

I tried modifying the options of Moodle with no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use guest access

First, use the auto login option for the guest role.

Go to Site administration > Permissions > User policies

Then enable the option for `autologinguests`

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Guest_role

Then in the course, go to Course administration > Users > Enrolment methods

Then enable "Guest access" by clicking the eye.

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Guest_access